# Not getting Sharp Corners using crease method

Tags: mesh

Using crease method or mark sharp method certain corners are not sharp after sub-division.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can solve this, if you put a crease on the perpendicular edge it will sharpen it and this is not what your want. But you can fix that with pure topology

Comment: @moonboots The entire thing is in quads. I am not sure now what can i further do so that creasing method will give sharp corners? A similar angle is just above that edge but it has sharpened perfectly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with crease, I personally prefer to use topology, I know you can fix this with topology. What angle are you talking about when you say it works? Maybe share your file, at least the part with your problem, so that we can give a try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots You were right. I finally figured out how to sharpen the corner. Crease sharpens corners that has only 2 edges. If there is a 3rd edge then crease won't sharpen. But now another question remains is how to sharpen outward corner.

Comment: which corner do you mean? maybe share your file